# .split + regex not working in web browser

Tags: javascript, regex, split

In visual studio code, this runs fine.

What is supposed to happen:
1. Load text file
2. Split it into paragraphs and save them to an array
3. Lastly it should log that array.

What happens:
1. It loads text file
2. It doesn't split it by paragraphs.
3. It logs the array of a single value to the console.

As you can see with my experiments, I've tried splitting by a space (which it does fine) but for some reason, splitting by paragraph is giving it trouble.

Is there something I need to include to get regex to work? This is on Google Chrome fwiw.

```js
const readTxt = (file) => {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        console.log('Book Loaded - Success!')
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        book = JSON.stringify(allText);
        sentenceCollectionRaw = book.split(/(?:\r\n){2,}/);
        //sentenceCollectionRaw = book.split(' ');
        //sentenceCollectionRaw = book;
        console.log('Book split - Success!')
        console.log(sentenceCollectionRaw);
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>X</title>
  <script language="javascript" src="CommaRemove.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Read Text</h1>

  <body onload="readTxt('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/120/120-0.txt');">

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the line endings are CRLF? Try `/(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}/`

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] of the split with relevant input

Comment: Have you tried with `\n` instead of `\r\n`? Line breaks are different in Linux vs Windows (CRLF vs LF)

Comment: Hi Guys, I've updated it using the Snippet editor, although it's giving me some different issues as the .txt file is somewhere else. (I assume that's why it doesn't like ie.)

Comment: The `englishxp.co.uk` site is not configured correctly for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not returned to a `OPTIONS` request. Thus any `XMLHttpRequest` calls from other sites are blocked by the browsers.
This is not what you want answered, so instead you should include a small portion of the file in code.

Comment: Is there a way to include the txt file here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this but it still isn't doing it. I JSON.stringify and it shows that \r and \n are still there after running this code.

Comment: Use pastebin.com to share text

Comment: I've just tested and it is able to split by full stop, using regex. Looks like it is purely on how it is handling these \r and \n

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It just didn't like this format: `(/(?:\r\n){2,}/)`
But... for some reason is fine with `("\n")`

I'm curious if anyone knows why?